# An error occurred while compiling the project angular, error TS2322

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

At compilation of the project at me such error flies:

```
Date: 2018-06-23T07:09:31.526Z
Hash: 850794f8281827da9d4b
Time: 4886ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.15 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 10.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 326 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/services/task.ts(46,5): error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void | Task>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Task>'.
Type 'void | Task' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Task'.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Swears on this piece of code:

```
42    create(task): Promise<Task> {
43      task['due_date'] = task['due_date']['formatted'];
44      let body = JSON.stringify({task: task});
45      const url = `${this.tasksUrl}?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
46      return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
47       .toPromise()
48       .then(res => res.json() as Task)
49       .catch(error => {
50        this.handleError(error, 'Could not create task!')
51      });
52    }
```

Tell me how can I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: Well, your catch doesn't return anything, so it returns void, so it's a Promise<Task | void>. And you declared that your method returned a Promise<Task>. That said: why are you still using the deprecated Http service, instead of the much better HttpClient service? And why are you marshalling to JSON instead of letting the service do it for you?

Comment: The project was not written by me. I need to run it and study it, but I met such a mistake, I'm trying to fix it, but so far without result.
I already broke my head, so I turned for help here.